# Problemas no update do hibernate

Tags: java-ee, vraptor, java

Estou tendo alguns imprevistos com o `Hibernate` na minha aplicação.

Gostaria de saber se as implementações de `annotations` feitas na classe `java` são levadas para o banco de dados ou tratadas somente no interior do sistema, pois adicionei o `@NotNull` em um campo, e após o restart não levou esta implementação para o banco.

A minha configuração do `Hibernate` está como `update`, e campos são adicionados normalmente quando modificados.

Não entendi o motivo do `Hibernate` não ter modificado automaticamente isto no banco, e me levou a dúvida se essas `annotations` estão corretas.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

O `@NotNull` valida apenas no sistema pois faz parte da especificação do [Bean Validation](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), se você não quer o campo do banco nulo então você pode colocar `@Column(nullable = false`) que é a especificação do `JPA`

Ex:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private String nome;
```